# UISplitViewController showing grey bar

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

We're using UISplitViewController.  When displaying the detail view controller when not in "split mode" there is a grey bar at the top of the screen.  Does anyone know why this is happening.  The detail view displays correctly when in split view.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) on the subject I noticed that the detail view controller was embedded in a Navigation Controller.  We followed that practice and it solved the issue.  I'm not sure why this worked entirely.

Our Storyboard now looks like:

[image]